# System call for different Hardware Architecture?

Tags: c, architecture, operating-system, system-calls

I am assuimg the code will be written in C.

I have studied that compiler complies the code (Lexical Analysis, Syntax Analysis etc) and converts our code to assembly code and then assembler assembles the code to the machine code, which is finally executed on the Hardware.
So i have a doubt that whether the code which is written for the system calls is portable i.e. If i will compile the same code on some hardware will this code run?

Am i right in saying that the only architecture dependent part is compiler and system calls once compiled on other architectures will run fine?

Comment: @Blachshma Please lift the ban from me.. I need one more channce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System calls depends on Operating system as well as architecture. Most of the cases, your program should be re-compiled if the architecture or operating system is different.

for example `sbrk` and `brk` system calls which is used for malloc() i.e dynamic memory allocation not available in windows.

Refer how malloc is implemented in windows [Windows memory allocation questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199407/windows-memory-allocation-questions)

There are two types of system calls namely "machine architecture independent" and "machine architecture dependent" available.

If you use only machine architecture independent then there will be not much worry in porting.

**Coming to answer for your question :**
so it depends on which system call you used. But re-compile is must.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But as you said, there are 2 types of system calls arch independent and dependent. If I am calling architecture independent call, then why will i need a recompile?

Comment: The code has to be recompiled regardless of whether you use same system calls or not because different architectures have different instruction sets

Comment: @szx I agree with u that every architecture will have different instruction sets. So does this mean that the compiler will generate architecture dependent code or is the job of the assembler to generate machine specific code?

Comment: `malloc()` is not a system call. `malloc()` is just a standardized function in the C library, which is quite a different affair, and is made to be platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Not even considering the calls themselves, calling conventions greatly vary across hardware architectures. For example:

- Older x86: `int`
- Intel Newer x86/64: `sysenter`/`sysexit`
- AMD x86/64: `syscall`/`sysret`
- ARM: `swi 0x420000`

Obviously, none of these are really compatible. So while most x86 assembly will work on old x86, newer Intel x86/64, and AMD x86/64, the system calls are different. Even if you use abstractions like the Linux VDSO, it is still very architecture dependent as to where the VDSO even is.

For normal function calls, it has much more to do with calling conventions, which vary across architectures because of stack and register differences.

In other words, almost no assembly code is *ever* cross-architecture.